# Analyzing repeated choice data with respondent and item covariates: Sanity check on my model

Tags: mixed-model, multilevel-analysis

**For bounty, TL;DR:** Read the Setup, Hypothesis, and Update 2 sections. Is that model valid in terms of handling Type I and Type II errors, accounting for dependencies in data? Everything else is more background and me working through this problem.

### Setup

Imagine the following survey:

- $N$ = 200 respondents
- Each respondent sees 10 pairs of items across 10 trials
- On each trial, the respondent chooses the item they like more
- There are a total of 114 items
- Each respondent is randomly-assigned to see a subset of 20 of the 114 items, which are presented in pairs across the 10 trials
- There are covariates at both the respondent level ($X$) and the item level ($Z$)

The head of the data may look like this:

```
   id    question option     y item       x      z
   <fct> <fct>    <fct>  <dbl> <fct>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 31917 q01      1          1 dg    -0.674  1.12 
 2 31917 q01      2          0 bm    -0.674 -0.520
 3 31917 q02      1          0 eq    -0.674 -1.60 
 4 31917 q02      2          1 ew    -0.674  0.523
 5 31917 q03      1          0 ek    -0.674  0.122
 6 31917 q03      2          1 bg    -0.674  0.242
 7 31917 q04      1          1 de    -0.674  1.36 
 8 31917 q04      2          0 an    -0.674  1.08 
 9 31917 q05      1          0 ao    -0.674 -0.961
10 31917 q05      2          1 dy    -0.674  0.763
```

Where:

- `id` is a unique identifier for respondent
- `question` indicates the trial (`q01` to `q10`)
- `option` indicates if it was the item presented on the left side of the screen (1) or the right side of the screen (2)
- `y` indicates if it was chosen or not, where chosen = 1 and not chosen = 0
- `item` is a unique identifier for the item
- `x` is a covariate measured at the respondent-level (`id`)
- `z` is a covariate measured at the item-level (`item`)

Dummy data can be found in full at [this Pastebin link.](https://pastebin.com/ZevgHbJy)

### Hypothesis

I am testing an interaction between $X$ and $Z$ on choice. More specifically: I propose that the correlation between $Z$ and the probability of that item being chosen is negative; however, I believe that this negative relationship is stronger as $X$ increases. So, low $X$: coefficient describing relationship between $Z$ and the probability of being chosen is near zero. But high $X$: coefficient describing the relationship between $Z$ and the probability of chosen is negative.

### Possible Analysis

I see this as a multilevel/mixed effects model with a crossed (non-nested) design. Each observation has an outcome $Y$ of either being chosen (1) or not being chosen (0), which is predicted by fixed effects of $X$, $Z$, the and the interaction between the two. There are random intercepts set for the question, item, and respondent. I also allow the slope of $Z$ to vary by respondent—a random effect on that, as well.

I use R for analysis, so in `{lme4}` this model would look like:

```
library(lme4)
dat <- readr::read_csv("dummydata.csv")
mod <- glmer(
  y ~ x * z + (1 + z | id) + (1 | question) + (1 | item),
  dat,
  binomial
)
```

But this returns a singular fit:

```
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
```

Examining the variance-covariance of the random effects, we can see that this is because, perhaps, the random coefficient of `z` for each `id` is perfectly negatively correlated with the intercept for each `id` and there is no variance for question.

```
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance  Std.Dev. Corr 
 id       (Intercept) 1.109e-05 0.00333       
          z           3.004e-02 0.17333  -1.00
 item     (Intercept) 2.996e-01 0.54735       
 question (Intercept) 0.000e+00 0.00000       
Number of obs: 3780, groups:  id, 189; item, 114; question, 10
```

So I will not estimate that covariance. We also see that there is no variance by question, so we could drop that random effect.

So a simpler model could thus be:

```
mod2 <- glmer(y ~ x * z + (1 + z || id) + (1 | item), dat, binomial)
```

The double bar `||` indicating not to estimate the covariance between slope and intercept by `id`.

This is still singular, perhaps because there is no variance around the intercepts by `id` now:

```
Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 id     (Intercept) 0.00000  0.0000  
 id.1   z           0.02994  0.1730  
 item   (Intercept) 0.29960  0.5474  
Number of obs: 3780, groups:  id, 189; item, 114
```

So I will only specify random effects for (1) the slope of `z` by `id` and (2) the intercept for `item`:

```
mod3 <- glmer(y ~ x * z + (-1 + z | id) + (1 | item), dat, binomial)
```

I finally get a model that converges.

### Question

Does this analysis seem valid and test what I want to test? I believe it does, but I candidly am not an expert at crossed designs, especially with an interaction between variables that vary by different "levels" (respondent and item).

I don't necessarily like the approach I took here of pruning until I did not get a singular fit—can someone help explain why I was getting perfect covariances and null variances around intercepts in the random effects structure? I very much do not like a conclusion of "OK, no more warnings, I guess we are good!" So I'd like some insight here. I particularly don't understand why it appears I don't need to account for question by specifying a random intercept—I would assume I need to tell the model, somehow, what the item matchups were. Same with respondent: I'm not used to not having a random intercept for these very important grouping variables (respondent and item). So I'm stumped as to why I don't apparently need to do that here, given the lack of variance.

If this is not a valid way to model these data, how would you suggest testing the hypothesis?

---

### Update 1

So, I answered a few questions of mine above, but not all.

- Why is a random intercept for ID not necessary? Because all respondents were given 20 items to choose from, and they *had* to choose 10. So everyone has an intercept of 50%, which is, in logits, zero.
- Same for trial number: For each trial, one and only one must have been selected, leaving the other unselected. So always an estimate of 50%, or a logit of zero.

This still leaves unresolved: **How can I account for the perfect dependency between observations?** That is, if respondent 111 in trial 1 selects item one item, it means they necessarily did not select the other item.

I tried fitting another model that nests within pairs.

```
dat <- dat %>% 
  group_by(id, question) %>% 
  mutate(pair = paste(item, collapse = "_")) %>% 
  ungroup()

> head(dat)
# A tibble: 6 x 8
     id question option     y  item          x          z  pair
  <int>    <chr>  <int> <int> <chr>      <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>
1 31917      q01      1     1    dg -0.6740292  1.1242656 dg_bm
2 31917      q01      2     0    bm -0.6740292 -0.5198149 dg_bm
3 31917      q02      1     0    eq -0.6740292 -1.6025021 eq_ew
4 31917      q02      2     1    ew -0.6740292  0.5227728 eq_ew
5 31917      q03      1     0    ek -0.6740292  0.1217775 ek_bg
6 31917      q03      2     1    bg -0.6740292  0.2420761 ek_bg
```

Which looks like:

```
mod4 <- glmer(
  y ~ x * z + (-1 + z | id) + (1 | item) + (1 | pair),
  dat, 
  binomial
)
```

Again, singular fit, because each pair requires exactly half to be selected. So no variance around an estimate of zero for that intercept.

```
Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 pair   (Intercept) 0.00000  0.0000  
 id     z           0.02994  0.1730  
 item   (Intercept) 0.29959  0.5474  
Number of obs: 3780, groups:  pair, 1758; id, 189; item, 114
```

Right now, I'm basically artificially doubling the sample size, since, for example, the first two observations in the `head` of the data above are perfectly correlated. I could filter to just analyze data where option is 1 or only where option is 2... but then again, that would mean ignoring information about the item that was not selected.

Nevertheless, I get a singular fit when I do that.

```
dat2 <- dat %>% 
  filter(option == 1)

mod5 <- glmer(
  y ~ x * z + (-1 + z | id) + (1 | item),
  dat2, 
  binomial
)
```

Which, I suppose, is coming from the very limited variance in the slope for `z` suddenly:

```
Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance  Std.Dev. 
 id     z           7.044e-10 2.654e-05
 item   (Intercept) 2.911e-01 5.395e-01
Number of obs: 1890, groups:  id, 189; item, 114
```

---

### Update 2

A way I thought to get rid of the redundancies in the data (if I know Option 1 was selected, I know Option 2 was not with 100% certainty) while still retaining some information about both items.

I do the same as above, only look at option 1, but I first get the difference between the two items shown as a pair on the covariate of interest. I then use that as the predictor variable. What are opinions on this? I know that making a difference score is usually frowned-upon, but it seems like a good enough option here. The preparation and model is:

```
mod6 <- glmer(
  y ~ x * z_diff + (-1 + z_diff | id) + (1 | item),
  dat,
  binomial
)
```

This appears to be to be a valid model (that is, not open to worries about inflation of Type I or II errors, etc.) that gets at what I want. But still interested if people think (a) this is correct, and (b) if not, what can be done? The question has turned more so into a sanity check, but I hope it is instructive at least in thinking about crossed multilevel models.

Comment: The fact that you cannot estimate a random intercept for `id` is weird to me. Since these are the same people responding to the items, I would think that this is a key source of correlation that you would want/need to account for. Can you run a model with only the outcome and then the two random intercepts? What are the variance estimates out of that model? Is there appreciable variance in each?

Comment: @ErikRuzek In the final model, `mod6`, there is minimal variance in the intercept for `id` because the intercept describes how often people are to select the left option. This is about just over 50% overall, with little variation by person in that model. I can estimate it in an intercepts-only model, but it gets hung up with the other predictors because the variance is about 0.

Comment: Ok. I think I am still confused by the design of your study and the left-right distinction and how that maps onto your variables.

Comment: @ErikRuzek Every respondent was assigned to see 20 items. They were seen across 10 trials of pairs. Each item either appeared on the left or the right side of the screen. They selected which item they prefer. Since these two observations are entirely dependent on one another (if the left was selected, then the right one wasn't, etc.), what I did was only look at the items that appeared on the left. Then, a logistic regression could be fit: 1 if selected, 0 if not.

Comment: @ErikRuzek But I want to incorporate information from the variable on the right still. So what I did was take the difference in the attribute between the two items that appeared and treated that as a covariate of the item that appeared on the left. It is either some positive number above or some negative number below the other item it was paired with.

Comment: This is helpful. Is there evidence that the correlation between `z_diff` and `y` varies across persons? Does `mod6` fit the data better than a model where you got rid of the random slope for `z_diff`?

Comment: @ErikRuzek Yes! And it's predicted by `x` (individual-level predictor), hence the interaction. The relationship between `z_diff`and `y` is stronger as `x` increases.

Comment: Given this, I think your approach makes sense. This was not an easy thing to figure out. Nice work!

Comment: @ErikRuzek hah, thanks!